# Binding property only gets updated in code but not in the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

**Background:** In my View I have a `TextBlock` and a `TextBox`. As soon as the text changes in the TextBox the `TextChanged` event gets fired and after filtering a list, I want to update the property which is bound to the TextBlock.
In my case it's a counter that shows the number of contacts in the current list.

**Problem**: When I debug the property (ContactsCount) gets always updated correctly, but only in Code and not in the UI. Strangely enough the UI only updates after I delete the text from the TextBox, to the last list count, but not the actual one.

**Code**
View:

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContactsCount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
               d:Text="4 Contacts"/>
    <xctk:WatermarkTextBox Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                           Watermark="Search Contact"
                           Margin="20,10">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=SearchBoxTextChanged}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </xctk:WatermarkTextBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
public string ContactsCount
{
    get => contactsCount;
    set
    {
        contactsCount = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(ContactsCount);
    }
}

public string SearchText
{
    get => searchText;
    set
    {
        searchText = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(SearchText);
    }
}

public CommandHandler SearchBoxTextChanged { get; set; }
SearchBoxTextChanged = new CommandHandler(TextChanged);

private void TextChanged()
{
     var filteredList = contactsList.Where(c => c.FirstName != null && c.FirstName.Contains(searchText.ToLower(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || 
                                                       c.SecondName != null && c.SecondName.Contains(searchText.ToLower(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
     Contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>(filteredList);
     // Bug: Doesn't update the UI after ContactsCount gets changed
     ContactsCount = $"{Contacts.Count} Contacts";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post the code of your `OnPropertyChanged()` method, but I suspect if should be

```
OnPropertyChanged("SearchText");
```

or better

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SearchText));
```

i.e. pass in the name of the updated property, not its value.

Comment: That's not real - I really made such a dumb mistake.. Anyway you are totally right. In my case, I don't even need to write the property name and can leave the parameter empty.